# get the IP adress to use for a docker container on a network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My NAS is where I run my containers. It sits on `192.168.1.23` on my network.

I am running a few containers inside a user-defined network. Here is the `docker network inspect` (I've removed the containers manually) :

```
[
    {
        "Name": "traefik2_proxy",
        "Id": "fb2924fe59fbb0436c72f11cb028df832a473a165162ecf08b7e3a946cfa2d3c",
        "Created": "2020-05-13T23:23:16.16424119+08:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.90.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.90.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I have a specific container which is in that network at IP address `192.168.90.16` for which I have exposed the `9118` port using the following in my docker-compose :

```
ports:
  - target: 9118
    published: 9118
    protocol: tcp
```

This is the portainer screenshot :

[image]

I was expecting to be able to connect to that container using `192.168.1.23:9118` but I tried to no avail.

What am I missing ? Which setting do I need to change for that container to be visible at that port on my NAS IP address ?

Comment: what are the binded ports on 192.168.1.23 ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. 192.168.1.23 sits on my LAN so I have setup nothing on the ports.

Comment: so no binded ports I guess

Comment: 192.168.90.16:9118 looks exposed there was no 1.23 ? in your question can you give more details ?

Comment: It's all there in the question, not sure why you're saying it's not there. The server is 192.168.1.23 and the docker network is 192.168.90.XXX

Comment: it's the first line of the question

Comment: what is docker ps -a output for this , i want to understand your needs and give a solution not for rep.

Comment: sure give me a sec

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wXYEiLXq

Comment: ah it s listening on 9117 and i ve opened 9118

Comment: is it fixed ? or it seems you have to expose over traefik

Comment: Yes i figured it out, Needed 
`ports:
  - target: 9117
    published: 9118
    protocol: tcp`

Comment: your `ps -a` command was actually useful for me to realize that

Comment: have a good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port that the container was listening to was incorrect. I needed to modify the `ports` configuration to:

```
ports: 
  - target: 9117 
    published: 9118 
    protocol: tcp
```